# Customizing twitter bootstrap popover arrow

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

I could not find any relevant information on this, but I find it hard to swallow that it's not doable.

How can I customise the arrow for the popovers? I already did but changing the classes .arrow and such, but the position of the popover gets screwed up.

So, what is the correct way to do so? I couldn't find any documentation.

Following are the classes I've been using, so far the arrow looks wrong:

```
.popover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1010;
    display: none;
    padding: 5px;
}

    .popover.top {
        margin-top: -5px;
    }

    .popover.right {
        margin-left: 5px;
    }

    .popover.bottom {
        margin-top: 5px;
    }

    .popover.left {
        margin-left: -5px;
    }

    .popover.top .arrow {
        bottom: 0;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -5px;
        border-left: 5px solid transparent;
        border-right: 5px solid transparent;
        border-top: 5px solid #000000;
    }

    .popover.right .arrow {
        top: 50%;
        left: 0;
        margin-top: -5px;
        border-top: 5px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
        border-right: 5px solid #000000;
    }

    .popover.bottom .arrow {
        top: 0px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -5px;
        border-left: 9px solid transparent;
        border-right: 9px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 19px solid #000000;
    }

    .popover.left .arrow {
        top: 50%;
        right: 0;
        margin-top: -5px;
        border-top: 5px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
        border-left: 5px solid #000000;
    }

    .popover .arrow {
        position: absolute;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
    }

.popover-inner {
    padding: 3px;
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #000000;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.popover-title {
    padding: 9px 15px;
    line-height: 1;
    background-color: #252525;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    background-color: rgba(37, 37, 37, 0.7);
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #7e7e7e;
}

.popover-content {
    padding: 14px;
    background-color: #252525;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    background-color: rgba(37, 37, 37, 0.7);
}

    .popover-content p, .popover-content ul, .popover-content ol {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .popover-content table {
        background: transparent;
    }

        .popover-content table td {
            border: 0px;
            background: transparent;
            color: #7e7e7e;
        }
```

The arrow should be pointing to the red square
[image: Arrow should be pointing to the red square]

Thanks.

Comment: The correct way to do so is to style them, using CSS classes related to `.popover` and `.arrow` styles.  You haven't provided an example of what you're trying and what's not working, so that's the best we'll be able to offer.

Comment: Sorry, pasted code and screenshot.

Comment: Isn't `.popover.bottom .arrow` the style you need to modify?

Comment: You're seeing the result, there is something else missing, hence my question, if I knew exactly what I need to change, I wouldn't be bothering you people :)

Comment: Post a jsfiddle or a test page ... we cant help guessing .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twitter Bootstrap is based on [Less](http://lesscss.org/).

If you want to change the appearance of its arrows use the [bootstrap less variables](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less#L250-L264) to do so.

```
// Tooltips and popovers
// -------------------------
@tooltipColor:            #fff;
@tooltipBackground:       #000;
@tooltipArrowWidth:       5px;
@tooltipArrowColor:       @tooltipBackground;

@popoverBackground:       #fff;
@popoverArrowWidth:       10px;
@popoverArrowColor:       #fff;
@popoverTitleBackground:  darken(@popoverBackground, 3%);

// Special enhancement for popovers
@popoverArrowOuterWidth:  @popoverArrowWidth + 1;
@popoverArrowOuterColor:  rgba(0,0,0,.25);
```

If you are using Sass instead do the same with the [Sass Variables](https://github.com/jlong/sass-twitter-bootstrap/blob/master/lib/_variables.scss).

Sadly the [TB-Customizer](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html) doesn't have all the variables so you might have to compile it on your own.

**Edit:**

Good news the new [Bootstrap 3 customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) now provides these options.

Answer (score 16):

For anyone using a custom style.css to simply overwrite bootstrap without recompiling the LESS, the css rule you're looking for is `.popover.top > .arrow:after { border-top-color: yourColorHere; }` to change the color of just the arrow.

Comment: This fix worked well for me once I changed it to   `border-top-color: myColorHere;`

Comment: Superb! of course works with bottom popovers also: `.popover.bottom > .arrow:after { border-bottom-color: YourColorHere;}`

Answer (score 1):

Use these variables to customize tooltips:

```
@tooltip-max-width:       200px;
@tooltip-color:           #FFF;
@tooltip-bg:              #000;
@tooltip-opacity:         .9;
@tooltip-arrow-width:     5px;
@tooltip-arrow-color:     #000;
```

Check the docs here:
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#tooltips

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble adjusting popover border thickness.  To adjust this I added the @popoverBorderThickness to popovers.less, only those lines are changed.  I included the whole file for context.

```
//
// Popovers
// --------------------------------------------------


.popover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: @zindexPopover;
  display: none;
  max-width: 276px;
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: left; // Reset given new insertion method
  background-color: @popoverBackground;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
     -moz-background-clip: padding;
          background-clip: padding-box;
  border: @popoverBorderThickness solid @popoverOuterColor;
  .border-radius(6px);
  .box-shadow(0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2));

  // Overrides for proper insertion
  white-space: normal;

  // Offset the popover to account for the popover arrow
  &.top     { margin-top: -10px; }
  &.right   { margin-left: 10px; }
  &.bottom  { margin-top: 10px; }
  &.left    { margin-left: -10px; }
}

.popover-title {
  margin: 0; // reset heading margin
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 18px;
  background-color: @popoverTitleBackground;
  border-bottom: 1px solid darken(@popoverTitleBackground, 5%);
  .border-radius(5px 5px 0 0);

  &:empty {
    display: none;
  }
}

.popover-content {
  padding: 9px 14px;
}

// Arrows
//
// .arrow is outer, .arrow:after is inner

.popover .arrow,
.popover .arrow:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
}
.popover .arrow {
  border-width: @popoverArrowOuterWidth;
}
.popover .arrow:after {
  border-width: @popoverArrowWidth;
  content: "";
}

.popover {
  &.top .arrow {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -@popoverArrowOuterWidth;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    border-top-color: #999; // IE8 fallback
    border-top-color: @popoverArrowOuterColor;
    bottom: -@popoverArrowOuterWidth;
    &:after {
      bottom: @popoverBorderThickness * 1.414;// longer line gets thinner use Pythagorean theorem to correct
      margin-left: -@popoverArrowWidth;
      border-bottom-width: 0;
      border-top-color: @popoverArrowColor;
    }
  }
  &.right .arrow {
    top: 50%;
    left: -@popoverArrowOuterWidth;
    margin-top: -@popoverArrowOuterWidth;
    border-left-width: 0;
    border-right-color: #999; // IE8 fallback
    border-right-color: @popoverArrowOuterColor;
    &:after {
      left: @popoverBorderThickness * 1.414;// longer line gets thinner use Pythagorean theorem to correct
      bottom: -@popoverArrowWidth;
      border-left-width: 0;
      border-right-color: @popoverArrowColor;
    }
  }
  &.bottom .arrow {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -@popoverArrowOuterWidth;
    border-top-width: 0;
    border-bottom-color: #999; // IE8 fallback
    border-bottom-color: @popoverArrowOuterColor;
    top: -@popoverArrowOuterWidth;
    &:after {
      top: @popoverBorderThickness * 1.414;// longer line gets thinner use Pythagorean theorem to correct
      margin-left: -@popoverArrowWidth;
      border-top-width: 0;
      border-bottom-color: @popoverArrowColor;
    }
  }

  &.left .arrow {
    top: 50%;
    right: -@popoverArrowOuterWidth;
    margin-top: -@popoverArrowOuterWidth;
    border-right-width: 0;
    border-left-color: #999; // IE8 fallback
    border-left-color: @popoverArrowOuterColor;
    &:after {
      right: @popoverBorderThickness * 1.414;// longer line gets thinner use Pythagorean theorem to correct
      border-right-width: 0;
      border-left-color: @popoverArrowColor;
      bottom: -@popoverArrowWidth;
    }
  }

}
```