# How to style the arrow in a bootstrap popover?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap popover kicking in when a user clicks on the Contact link.  I managed to style the popover itself, but can't figure out how style the little arrow that points to the link.

What is that element?  What is the class?  I can't catch it in the F12 tools because it always goes away when I try to inspect the element.

Basically I want the background color of the arrow to match the popover.

[image]

Comment: Really? I suppose you have the code running, can't you open the dev tools and inspect the specific element to know how to target it with css? If it needs hover, just right click on the node that triggers it and activate the hover option.

Comment: @Vivick No, because the popover goes away when it loses focus.

Comment: What is the React :tm: way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like it is indicated in this [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230317/customizing-twitter-bootstrap-popover-arrow), you want to use this css rule :

```
.popover.top > .arrow:after{
  /*stuff here*/
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  It was actually `.popover.bottom > .arrow:after {border-bottom-color: #4d4d4d;}`, but you got me going on the right path!

Comment: Yeah I guess it depends on the direction of the popout x)! As an excuse I'd say that I never used bootstrap.